# How to maintain previous screens history in android application?

Tags: android

In my application have ten activities.

When I press the back button the 10 screens have saved history. But when I click the next button the new screen doesn't have any historical data.

How do I maintain a history when click on next button?
My intent code is

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
String Group = bundle.getString("GroupApVehicle");
Intent log = new Intent(EngineCompartment.this, FrontAxle.class);

Bundle bun = new Bundle();
bun.putString("Group", Group);
bun.putString("ECSCORE", _StrpretriScoreCount);
System.out.println("Enginegroup" + Group);
bun.putString("TestIDFA", strtestid);
log.putExtras(bun);
startActivityForResult(log,IPC_ID);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suggest you save your activity state by implementing the `onSaveInstanceState()` callback. Chances are after 10 different activities Android attempts to clean up the memory, saving the activity state ensures the OS knows you'd like to keep the history.

See here for more information: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html#ActivityState

Answer (score 1):

Please describe current state of your back stack (for example activities A -> B -> C -> D) and what behavior you want to implement(for example switching activities D -> B).

EDIT:

As I understand, you want to keep activity in memory and preserve it's state when user presses "back" button.
You can override behavior of back button with following piece of code:

```
    public void onBackPressed () {
        moveTaskToBack (true);
    }
```

But it's not guaranteed, that Android will keep you activity in memory. It could be destroyed, if the OS will need additional memory. The fix: you application should listen for onPause() and onResume() events in your activity. You have to serialize and deserialize your data, saving the activity's state when it is paused and resumed.

Also, you should add this attribute to each activity's block in AndroidManifest.xml, which you want to initialize only once and preserve it's state during application lifetime:

```
    android:launchMode="singleTask"
```

Then use following sample of code to switch between activities:

```
    Intent i = new Intent(C.this, B.class);
    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    startActivity(i);
```

You also can use Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT, but launchMode should be set to "singleTask" too.

Comment: D->C->B this is maintain a history.but This flow   B->C->D   can't

Answer (score 1):

You can store the history manually in sharedPreference.
It is a one of the data storage factor in android
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html